# Convert polyline to polygon Using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, c#, arcgis-10.2, line

I have a polyline and I want to convert it to a single polygon feature, I used this code but I get error while I can convert the same shapefile using feature to polygon on ArcGIS.
Where is my mistake?

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.FeatureToPolygon ftp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.FeatureToPolygon(path + "lines.shp", path + "polygons.shp");
        ftp.attributes = "NO_ATTRIBUTES";
        GP.Execute(ftp, null);
```

The path is set to

```
string path= System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\temp\Conversations\";
```

and the error that raises is:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I tried to change output path to

```
"E:/MASTER/Project/Semirom/file gis semirom/New Folder/gisiran.gdb/tester"
```

But I get the same error... Do you think I must set Environment workspace or something like that? I also use:

`ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.GPXtoFeatures` and `ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.PointsToLine(path + "points.shp", path + "lines.shp");` with the same settings and they works fine..:(

Is there any better approach to create a polygon?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the version of ArcGIS and the exact error you have received.

Comment: Also what are you variables _path_ set to?

Comment: @Vince I added error and I am using arcmap 10.2.1 and arcEngine as the same version

Comment: @Hornbydd I added the path to my post

Comment: I also tried this function using arcpy and If worked fine but I cant run it with C# with the same parameters that I used in arcpy

Comment: You should be able to get an error code from the geoprocessing tool which should give you slightly more info about what the issue is.

Comment: @thehealingprocess how can I get Error from Geoprocessing tool?I just get Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. can you help me with it?

Comment: GP.GetMessages(esriGPMessageSeverity.<severity type here>) - you will specify the severity of messages you want this function to return (e.g. warning / error etc...). The messages returned are similar to the messages you will see in the results window in Arc when running a GP tool. I would call GetMessages inside a catch block.

Comment: @thehealingprocess thanks my friend...I got the reason..It says ---------------------------

---------------------------
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed.
Failed to execute (FeatureToPolygon).
Which licence level I have to active?Advance?I activated it on LicenceControlTool But I still get this error.I am sure that featureToPolygon works on ArcMap

Comment: @Majid It appears to require an ArcInfo (advanced) licence. But you say it works for you in ArcMap toolbox?

Comment: @thehealingprocess Yes I it works great on ArcMap Toolbox,I think I have to initiate licence in ArcEngine application for ArcInfo,I already have down the advance licence for it but the same error ..Do you have tried it before?Can you give me the method that you initiated ArcInfo advanced licence in your applications?

Comment: @Majid The solution to check for ArcInfo licence below (by Deke) should work

Comment: @thehealingprocess Thanks my friend,I tried it but I get the same error :(,anyway I managed to create polygon using another approach and I worked fine..But I cant show IPolygon on mapview..Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @Majid You can't just add a polygon feature directly to the map. You need to either save it in a feature class or as a shapefile. You can however add it as a graphic object, use this function: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000067000000

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools;

FeatureToPolygon featureToPolygon = new FeatureToPolygon();

featureToPolygon.in_features = pInWorkspace.PathName + "\\" + pInFeatureClassName.FeatureDatasetName.Name + "\\Temp_Line_UnNamed";
featureToPolygon.out_feature_class = pInWorkspace.PathName + "\\" + pInFeatureClassName.FeatureDatasetName.Name + "\\Master_Poly_UnNamed";

featureToPolygon.attributes = "ATTRIBUTES";
featureToPolygon.cluster_tolerance = 0.01;
featureToPolygon.label_features = "";

RunTool(gp, featureToPolygon, null);

public static void RunTool(Geoprocessor geoprocessor, IGPProcess process, ITrackCancel tc)
    {
    // set overwrite option to true
    geoprocessor.OverwriteOutput = true;

    // execute tool
    try
    {
         geoprocessor.Execute(process, null);
         ReturnMessages(geoprocessor);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
         ReturnMessages(geoprocessor);
    }
}

private static void ReturnMessages(Geoprocessor gp)
{
    if (gp.MessageCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= gp.MessageCount - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gp.GetMessage(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This??

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
    Application.Run(new frmHydroLinesToPolygons());
}

private void frmHydroLinesToPolygons_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool bLicenseAvailable;

    // initializes ArcObjects components runtime environment.
    // This class must be first Arcobject created 
    IAoInitialize aoInitialize = new AoInitializeClass();
    esriLicenseStatus status;

    // checks for ArcInfo License - essential when converting feature to polygons 
    status = aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced); //.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo); //.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView);

    // check if license is available
    if ((status == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable) || (status == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAlreadyInitialized) || (status == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseCheckedOut))
    {
        bLicenseAvailable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        bLicenseAvailable = false;
    }

    // if not licensed - initialize license
    if (bLicenseAvailable != true)
    {
        if (status == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseNotLicensed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry... An ArcInfo License is Required for this Program");
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I get this error:Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed. Failed to execute (FeatureToPolygon).I have ArcInfo licence on my pc and FeatureToPolygon works fine on ArcMap but I get this error,I tried to initiate advanced licence in programs runtime but got no chance

Comment: Have you tried to license the required extension to use this tool? not only the arcmap, this is done in the app that you are developing

Comment: I had added this before your edit but there is not any chance to work and that error comes..   status = aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced); //.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo); //.esriLicenseProductCodeArcView);..anyway I find another way to creat polygons from points and I think it works..Now I want to show the result in map view Can you suggest me the best way to show a Ipolygon feature to mapView?without saveing it on disk or sth like that?

Comment: Sorry.. Cant help you on the mapview

Comment: @XtianGIS Yes,I have tried spatial analize and 3d analise before using this tool

Answer (score 0):

You require to check out the licenses of the extensions required:

```
aoInitialize.CheckOutExtension(esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCode3DAnalyst);
        aoInitialize.CheckOutExtension(esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst);
```

> When using an ArcView or ArcEditor license, a program must explicitly use AoIntialize, and the product must be set to ArcView or ArcEditor, or the program fails. By default, the geoprocessor always assumes an ArcInfo license is required for execution of a script; therefore, if a program does not explicitly set the product required by the tools it executes, an ArcInfo license is initialized. See the following code example:

check this example:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

  //Initialize the application.
  esriLicenseStatus licenseStatus = esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseUnavailable;
  IAoInitialize m_AoInitialize = new AoInitializeClass();
  licenseStatus = m_AoInitialize.Initialize
    (esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo);
  licenseStatus = m_AoInitialize.CheckOutExtension
    (esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst);

  // Initialize the geoprocessor.         
  Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
  Slope tSlope = new Slope();
  tSlope.in_raster = @"E:\Data\demlatgrd";
  tSlope.out_raster = @� � �E:  \
    Data  \
    aspect03 ";gp.Execute(tSlope, null);

  licenseStatus = m_AoInitialize.CheckInExtension
    (esriLicenseExtensionCode.esriLicenseExtensionCodeSpatialAnalyst);
  m_AoInitialize.Shutdown();
  m_AoInitialize = null;

}
```